# Show that a norm is continuous in 0 (with the 2-norm )

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

In this proof I want to use the definition of continuity with the 2-norm.
Let N : $\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be another norm.
I want to show that N is continuous in 0.

To do that I took a sequence $(x_k)$ included in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k = 0$
but then I don't know how to conclude that $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}  N(x_k) = 0 = N(0)$

(Here, I can't use the fact that all norms are equivalent.)

Thank you by advance for your help.

Comment: sorry I'm deleting my answer since it was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salut Chloé?, je vais répondre en anglais pour pas qu'ils suppriment la réponse

Consider an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb R^n$,  $N(x) = N(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i e_i)$ where $\lambda_i$ are scalars and $e_i$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$'s basis.  Now use triangular inequality and then the fameux théorème des gendarmes.